# Could you support my documentation beta Magento proposal?

Tags: discussion, magento, documentation

**Note:** You have to be on the Documentation beta in order to contribute.

I have posted a proposal on the Stack Overflow Documentation Beta site [for the creation of Magento documentation](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/documentation/magento/commit).

I've been trying this new SO site for a bit and it is quite nice.

If the Magento proposal has passed (currently 1 out of 3 committed), then we can start creating and writing documentation.

**Isn't there Magento documentation already at http://docs.magento.com/?** Sure there is and it is constantly being improved. The SO Documentation site is all about examples that are lacking in documentation most of the time. Read all about the idea of the Documentation SO [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/1306684).

**OK BUMP**

Documentation is out of private beta and now in the open. Go here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/magento
And support my proposal for Magento docs ;)

---

**UPDATE**

20 mins. ago it was created!

Comment: Apparently, I forgot about the fact that documentation is still in private beta...

Comment: We're watching this initiative.

Comment: So will this documentation be just for M1 or will it also be for M2? And I'm assuming that if this does well enough, Magento, Inc will probably adopt from it into their own docs...

Comment: The Documentation system supports multiple versions. @ryanF the SE Documentation is all about examples. The official Magento Docs try to cover the whole product in basis. There will inevitably be overlap in some extend, but the two do differ.

Comment: @7ochem cool, thanks. Just checking as when I went over to the docs the first few links I saw showed M1 code..so I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2):

I wish I could but I haven't committed to the Area 51 proposal :(

[image]

Plus when I click the suggested link I get a 404

[image]

Couldn't find the related Area 51 proposal using the search.

Anyway, yes that's a great idea I 100% approve even if I can't support your tag request.

Comment: It's out of beta now!

Comment: @7ochem so what should we start doing ?