# Is the new Documentation feature (beta) for Stack Overflow offered to community StackExchange sites like ours?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderators, documentation

There already appears to be [something kicked off over at Stack Overflow for Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/magento), but it would seem like our [Magento Stack Exchange site](http://magento.stackexchange.com) would be the ideal place for this to exist vs. there...

Has the Stack Exchange community engagement team reached out to any of our Moderators to discuss this?  I hate to see effort wasted and it also feels like we might be an ideal candidate for beta-testing this feature given Magento's recently emphasized transparency and support of the [Magento Dev Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/) effort...

After digging into this a bit more I've discovered @7ochem has a [related post on the newly established Magento SO Documentation Beta Site](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/919/could-you-support-my-documentation-beta-magento-proposal)

Comment: I think it was a @7ochem initiative I hope hell be able to enlight you

Comment: Thanks for that update, Raphael - I've updated the post with a link to @7ochem meta post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Sorry, have been away for a full month :D</sup>

The Documentation site is a separate site within the StackExchange network and is not only a sub-site for StackOverflow (although it is located there). It can facilitate documentation on all kinds of topics (as you can see) from big names like PHP/.NET/SQL/Java to "never-heard-of-it" stuff like Jekyll/lodash/zeromq. Documentation sections (tags) are created by the community and thus I've proposed a Magento tag/documentation.

So what is the Documentation's place in all that's Magento? There's Magento SE for specific Q&A and there's the Magento official Docs for basic walk-through style reads. Documentation falls in between, with an overlap here and there. Documentation is all about giving many examples on general cases. So it is not as specific as Q&A, and where the official docs may lack examples on every use case, the SE Documentation site can provide that.

Also it allows for examples of full modules, something that will be flagged as too broad here on the Q&A.

In addition to that, you are encouraged to link to the documentation sections. This will the writer/contributer of a documentation topic a reputation bonus for being referenced (cited): https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation (look for "cite")

There's a lot of meta discussions on the new Documentation site, so feel free to browse https://meta.stackexchange.com/ for it

Answer (score 6):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think that the documentation feature is available only for the mothership website.
I randomly clicked on a few websites [in here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) and none of them have this feature.
My bet (read hope) is that when this feature gets out of beta it will be available for some websites in the SE network.
But to answer your question, no, nobody reached out to the moderators for this.

Comment: Thanks for digging into this for us, Marius! I'll follow up when I return home from MageTitans USA and see what I can dig up. This helps and is enough for me to get back to celebrating my 40th birthday with our #RealMagento community down in Austin, TX. 

Comment: Happy birthday then, and have fun at MT USA. Say hello from me to the people there.